# IIS 7 is not responding

Tags: iis, iis-7

IIS7 based web site was working a day ago, now nothing.
The browser just says "waiting for www.sitename.com". I am running the browser on the server with admin rights. No error messages, no log entries, Firefox just waits indefinitely (same with IE). Where do I start? I am clueless.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd start by making sure the problem isn't just you. Have you done that? If not, try http://isup.me/.

Comment: You could point out what type of application is running, which additional components are installed. At the moment it just sounds like "it doesn't work and it wasn't me".

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to consider opening IIS Manager on the server and finding your site in the tree on the left.  Once you find it, click on the site icon and then look to see if there is a little square icon overlay.  That will tell you if your site is stopped.  If so, in the pane on the extreme right hand side there is section titled "Manage Web Site" that contains an option to start it.

If the site was not stopped, try clicking the link on the browse link that appears under the "Browse Web Site" section in the pane on the right.  If your site doesn't come up after doing so, then you'll probably want to try using the "restart" link from the "Manage Web Site" section.

If none of the above work, you may need to try restarting the service titled "World Wide Web Publishing Service" from the Windows Services manager interface or rebooting the server.  If all else fails, the next steps that I'd consider are browsing the Windows Event Log and your IIS logs for errors and/or deleting and recreating the website.

Hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but none of these seem to work. I even restarted the whole server. The web site is not stopped.  It has a little globe icon only, which is normal. Still, nothing in the logs, and the browser does not give any errors... firefox is just waiting and waiting.

Comment: It turned out that a malformed PHP scrpit went into an infinite loop. This is why no errors were seen. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Ouch.  That sounds like it would be close to finding a needle in a haystack.  Glad that you figured it out.